# Bing Maps API -- setBounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bing-maps

I'm converting a mapping utility from Gmap to Bing. In Google Maps, you can easily add markers to the map, and each time you add a marker, you add the location of the marker to a bounds object, then call `setBounds()` on the map to recenter the map to fit all markers.

I cannot find a similar method to work with Bing Maps, and the docs are pretty lousy compared to Google's.

So far I've got the map created and markers added-- but the map stays stuck at the initial view, rather than updating to fit the markers.

Is there an equivalent of the setBounds method for the Bing javascript API, or is there another way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this in Bing is:

1) Use the LocationRect.fromLocations function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427621.aspx) to create a bounding box from your pushpins locations
2) pass the LocationRect created in one to the map objects setViewFunction as part of the ViewOptions parameter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427628.aspx